# Ocultar uma imagem quando uma página web for carregada num dispositivo móvel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso ocultar uma imagem quando uma página web for carregada num dispositivo móvel. O problema é que ele não pode alterar a estrutura HTML da página, somente no Bootstrap, CSS e JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando uma função que verifica se é dispositivo móvel.

Execute um loop `for` para pegar a index da `<img>` pelo seu `src`. Crie uma variável qualquer (`elem_src`) com a URL da imagem que você quer tratar e em seguida faça um `if` para esconder a imagem (caso seja móvel) ou não fazer nada (caso seja desktop):

```
<img height="100" src="http://gclipart.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Thumbs-up-thumb-clip-art-clipart-8.jpeg" />

<script>
function ehMovel(){
    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

window.onload = function(){
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var elem_src = "http://gclipart.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Thumbs-up-thumb-clip-art-clipart-8.jpeg"; //coloque aqui o caminho da imagem
    for(x=0; x<elem.length; x++){
        if(elem[x].src == elem_src){
            var elem_idx = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(ehMovel()) elem[elem_idx].style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Só cuidado que, se a tag body tiver um evento onload nela, pode dar problema, @PauloGalego.

Comment: @Dudaskank Não dá problema nenhum, pois se tivesse, cada `onload` seria executado em paralelo, sem problema nenhum.

Comment: Pessoal sem  palavras, estou testando eu volto com retorno sem falta, muito obrigado a todos

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde, usa js para esconde a imagem.
Exemplo:

```
$('#id').hide(); /* Usa id ou uma classe */
```

Ou CSS:

```
.class ou #id {
    visibility:hidden;
};
```

jQuery que checka se é mobile

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  // Aqui faria o hide() ou add a classe de css
}
```

Comment: é bom mencionar que isso é JQuery.

Comment: Sim, add uma opção de css também.

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal, mas eu preciso que esconda a imagem somente quando for mobile, esse comando esconde permanentemente.

Comment: Sim, teria que criar uma função para ver quando é mobile e quando é desktop. Ai vc add a classe ou o js.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar as classes do bootstrap como hidden-lg, hidden-md, hidden-sm e hidden-xs por exemplo :

```
<img alt="" class="hidden-xs" src="caminho">
```

se você não pode alterar o html , tem a opção por JS que seria

```
 $("#IDdaImagem").addClass("hidden-xs");
```

Comment: Quero agradecer a todos pela ajuda. A Miha página tme apenas a seguinte tag: <img src="......">     Eu preciso ocultar ela sme alterar nada no html...

Comment: @PauloGalego vc pode colocar a class na tag <img>